# Show Previous/Next Posts navigation only inside the same category

Tags: categories, pagination

Is it possible to force previous/next navigation to browse through the posts (back and forth) that are only inside the same category (and to exclude other categories)?

Answer (score 5):

The [functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) accept an `$in_same_cat` argument, the default value of which is false. Just set that to true.

```
previous_post_link($format, $link, true);
next_post_link($format, $link, true);
```

Comment: Thanks!  My wife asked for this and your answer made it a 10 minutes job to customize my child theme!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in single.php loop to display nex/pre links in same category

```
<?php


get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

 // Previous/next post navigation.
previous_post_link('%link', 'Before', true );
next_post_link( '%link', 'Next', true );

?>
```